# Join multi-line strings into one string

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to parse a log file that looks like this:

```
24/01/2016, 11:50:17 pm: ‎Line to skip
24/01/2016, 11:50:17 pm: ‎Line to skip
25/01/2016, 11:51:47 pm: User1: Message one is here
25/01/2016, 11:53:04 pm: User2: A long message that spans multiple lines, so I have to write a really long and tedious message here to illustrate my point. The point is that this message is really long and 

can
[span]

Several lines.
24/01/2016, 11:51:47 pm: User3: My first message
27/10/2017, 12:54:03 am: ‎‪+44 ‬012 3456789 left
28/10/2017, 02:54:03 pm: User3: My second message!
```

---

```
rawData <- structure(list(V1 = c("24 01 2016, 11:50:17 pm: ‎Line to skip", 
        "24 01 2016, 11:50:17 pm: ‎Line to skip", "24 01 2016, 11:51:47 pm: User1: Message one is here", 
        "24 01 2016, 11:53:04 pm: User2: A long message that spans multiple lines, so I have to write a really long and tedious message here to illustrate my point. The point is that this message is really long and ", 
        "can", "[span]", "Several lines.", "24 01 2016, 11:51:47 pm: User3: My first message", 
        "27 10 2017, 12:54:03 am: ‎‪+44 ‬012 3456789 left")), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, 
        -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Each message starts with a date, and I'm having trouble parsing messages that span multiple lines (like on line 4).

Here's what I have so far:

```
suppressMessages(library(lubridate))
suppressMessages(library(dplyr)) 
suppressMessages(library(plyr))
suppressMessages(library(tidyr))

parseR <- function(file='data/chat_log.txt',drop="44"){
  rawData <- read.delim(file, quote = "", 
                  row.names = NULL, 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                  header = F)


  # remove blank lines
  # rawData<-rawData[!apply(rawData == "", 1, all),]

  empty_lines = grepl('^\\s*$', rawData)
  rawData = rawData[! empty_lines]

  # join multi line messages into single line
  # rawData$V1<-gsub("[\r\n]", " ", rawData$V2)

  sepData<-suppressWarnings(separate(rawData, V1, c("datetime", "sender", "message"), sep = ": ", extra = "merge"))

  sepData$message <- trimws(sepData$message)
  sepData$sender<-factor(sepData$sender)

  data <- sepData %>% 
    filter(!is.na(message)) %>%
    filter(!grepl(drop, sender)) %>%
    droplevels() 

  cleanData<-separate(data, datetime, c("date", "time"), sep = " ", remove =TRUE)
  cleanData$date<-ymd(cleanData$date)
  cleanData$time<-hms(cleanData$time)

  return(cleanData)
}
```

---

However, when I inspect the returned data frame, muliti line messages are not being parsed correctly:

```
> head(parseR())
        date        time sender                                                                                                                                                                       message
1 2016-01-25 23H 51M 47S  User1                                                                                                                                                           Message one is here
2 2016-01-25  23H 53M 4S  User2 A long message that spans multiple lines, so I have to write a really long and tedious message here to illustrate my point. The point is that this message is really long and
3 2016-01-24 23H 51M 47S  User3                                                                                                                                                              My first message
4 2017-10-28  14H 54M 3S  User3
```

Can anyone suggest a way of removing blank lines and joining text that doesn't start with a date into one string?

**Desired format for line 4:**

```
25/01/2016, 11:53:04 pm: User2: A long message that spans multiple lines, so I have to write a really long and tedious message here to illustrate my point. The point is that this message is really long and can [span] Several lines.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a caveman approach to this problem. I'm taking the timestamp to be a unique beginning of line identifier. If none is present, it pastes the line (or element) to the previous one. The example below is adapted to a vector, but it can easily be changed to work on other classes, such as matrices or data.frames.

```
rd <- c("24 01 2016, 11:50:17 pm: Line to skip", 
        "24 01 2016, 11:50:17 pm: Line to skip", "24 01 2016, 11:51:47 pm: User1: Message one is here", 
        "24 01 2016, 11:53:04 pm: User2: A long message that spans multiple lines, so I have to write a really long and tedious message here to illustrate my point. The point is that this message is really long and ", 
        "can", "[span]", "Several lines.", "24 01 2016, 11:51:47 pm: User3: My first message", 
        "27 10 2017, 12:54:03 am: ‪+44 ‬012 3456789 left")
rd

out <- rep(NA, length(rd))

gr <- 1
for (i in 1:length(rd)) {
  # if starting with timestamp, save into out and move on (gr)
  find.startline <- grepl("^\\d{2} \\d{2} \\d{4}, \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} (am|pm):", rd[i])
  if (find.startline) {
    out[gr] <- rd[i]
    gr <- gr + 1
  }

  if (!find.startline) {
    # if doesn't start with timestamp, append to previous (ss)
    ss <- gr - 1
    out[ss] <- paste(out[ss], rd[i])
  }
}

# if there are any multiline comments, some residual NAs should be present, removed
out <- out[!is.na(out)]
out

[1] "24 01 2016, 11:50:17 pm: Line to skip"                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[2] "24 01 2016, 11:50:17 pm: Line to skip"                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[3] "24 01 2016, 11:51:47 pm: User1: Message one is here"                                                                                                                                                                                     
[4] "24 01 2016, 11:53:04 pm: User2: A long message that spans multiple lines, so I have to write a really long and tedious message here to illustrate my point. The point is that this message is really long and  can [span] Several lines."
[5] "24 01 2016, 11:51:47 pm: User3: My first message"                                                                                                                                                                                        
[6] "27 10 2017, 12:54:03 am: *+44 ,012 3456789 left"
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose something similar to Roman's solution but in Tidyverse world:

```
rawData %>%
  mutate( 
    MgsNo = (!substr( V1, 1, 1) %>% # take first character
                 as.numeric %>% # convert to numeric - produces NAs for non-numeric values
                 is.na) %>% # produces True(1) and False(0) ( by ! I reverse those)
      cumsum ) %>% # then cumulative sum as Mgs NO e.g. 1,1,1,0,0,1 -> 1,2,3,3,3,4
  group_by( MgsNo) %>% 
  do( MgsBody = paste( .$V1 , collapse = "")) %>% # concatenate all in each MgsNo group 
  select( MgsBody) %>%
  pull
```

Comment: Will this work if the first character in the line is a number (but not from a date)?

Comment: You are right. It may happen that numbers may occur as a first character in second line of message. Then it will not work. Your solution is more general, therefore better. I guess It would be better, if I would use something similar to your code for find.startline. I never had patience to properly learn regular expression magic. Learnt something new, thx.

Comment: Life is better with regex. :)